# SQL Server - restart running count on change

Tags: sql, sql-server

**The schema**

Simplified, a sales table with non-unique sales IDs.  Within each ID there will be a sale of an element S, which can be followed by a sale of up to two elements L linked to the element S.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Sales
    ([id] int, [element] varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO Sales
    ([id], [element])
VALUES
    (100, 'S'),
    (100, 'S'),
    (100, 'L'),
    (100, 'L'),
    (100, 'S'),
    (100, 'L'),
    (101, 'S'),
    (101, 'L'),
    (101, 'L'),
    (101, 'S'),
    (101, 'L')
;
```

**The expected outcome**

Pivot the sales data with the expected outcome being:

```
id | S element | L1   | L1
---+-----------+------+----
100| S         |      |
100| S         | L    | L
100| S         | L    |
101| S         | L    |
101| S         | L    | L
```

**My attempt**

I've attempted to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` to count instances of L-elements assigned to each S-element but I don't know how to reset the count after each new S-element.  My query

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by Id) AS rows,
        id,
        element,
        CASE element WHEN 'S'
          THEN 0
          ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY element ORDER BY id)
        END AS cnt
FROM Sales
ORDER BY rows
```

Returns

```
rs  id  el  cnt
1   100 S   0
2   100 S   0
3   100 L   1
4   100 L   2
5   100 S   0
6   100 L   3
7   101 S   0
8   101 L   4
9   101 S   0
10  101 L   5
```

Where I would like to see instead something like:

```
rs  id  el  cnt
1   100 S   0
2   100 S   0
3   100 L   1
4   100 L   2
5   100 S   0
6   100 L   1
7   101 S   0
8   101 L   1
9   101 S   0
10  101 L   1
```

Which could be pivoted using the value in the cnt column.

Any help with the problem, or alternative approaches!, would be appreciated.

Comment: You really need something else than just non-unique `ID` to order by. Having just these two columns `id` and `element` is not enough. Tables in SQL don't have any intrinsic order that you could rely on. Once you provide this extra data, we can think further, for example, use gaps-and-islands approach.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - thanks for your input but I cannot make up data which does not exist.

Comment: Then, whatever query you come up with will return undefined results. Sometimes it may return expected result, sometimes it may return something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need something else than just non-unique `ID` to order by. Having just these two columns `id` and `element` is not enough. Tables in SQL don't have any intrinsic order that you could rely on.

The code below that populates a temp table generates `IDENTITY` values in arbitrary order. In this specific example `IDENTITY` values happen to be generated in the same order as rows are written in the `VALUES` clause, but it is **not** guaranteed at all. This behaviour is undefined. You should never rely on this. Your data must have some sort of `RowID`.

**Sample data**

```
create table #SalesWithId
(
rowId int identity(1,1)
, salesId int not null
, element char(1) not null
)

insert into #SalesWithId
( salesId, [element])
values
(100, 'S'),
(100, 'S'),
(100, 'L'),
(100, 'L'),
(100, 'S'),
(100, 'L'),
(101, 'S'),
(101, 'L'),
(101, 'L'),
(101, 'S'),
(101, 'L');
```

**Query**

Once you do have some unique `RowID` to order by, the query becomes a variation of gaps-and-islands. Your code was very close. You just need to subtract two sets of row-numbers.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SalesID ORDER BY RowID) AS rn1
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SalesID, Element ORDER BY RowID) AS rn2
    FROM
        #SalesWithId
)
SELECT
    *
    ,rn1-rn2 as GroupID
    ,CASE element WHEN 'S'
        THEN 0
        ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SalesID, Element, rn1-rn2 ORDER BY RowID)
    END AS Cnt
FROM CTE
ORDER BY RowID;


DROP TABLE #SalesWithId;
```

**Result**

```
+-------+---------+---------+-----+-----+---------+-----+
| rowId | salesId | element | rn1 | rn2 | GroupID | Cnt |
+-------+---------+---------+-----+-----+---------+-----+
|     1 |     100 | S       |   1 |   1 |       0 |   0 |
|     2 |     100 | S       |   2 |   2 |       0 |   0 |
|     3 |     100 | L       |   3 |   1 |       2 |   1 |
|     4 |     100 | L       |   4 |   2 |       2 |   2 |
|     5 |     100 | S       |   5 |   3 |       2 |   0 |
|     6 |     100 | L       |   6 |   3 |       3 |   1 |
|     7 |     101 | S       |   1 |   1 |       0 |   0 |
|     8 |     101 | L       |   2 |   1 |       1 |   1 |
|     9 |     101 | L       |   3 |   2 |       1 |   2 |
|    10 |     101 | S       |   4 |   2 |       2 |   0 |
|    11 |     101 | L       |   5 |   3 |       2 |   1 |
+-------+---------+---------+-----+-----+---------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

In my solution shown below, first I insert into a temp table and get a sequential, non-skipping, Id into place in order to ensure that the data will come out the same every time.  It's very important to be sequential and non-skipping or my solution will not work.  I believe there needs to be a way to guarantee the order, which I didn't see in the setup.  So the sql speaks for itself, but quickly I will try to explain.  We go through the table and if you are an S then you are a 0, else I find the first S before me in the same salesId and get its rowId. Then just minus the rowIds. So if I am rowId 9, I should look back and see the S on row 7 and so 9-7 and you get your 2.

```
drop table if exists #SalesWithId

create table #SalesWithId
(
    rowId int identity(1,1)
  , salesId int not null
  , element char(1) not null
)

insert into #SalesWithId
    ( salesId, [element])
values
    (100, 'S'),
    (100, 'S'),
    (100, 'L'),
    (100, 'L'),
    (100, 'S'),
    (100, 'L'),
    (101, 'S'),
    (101, 'L'),
    (101, 'L'),
    (101, 'S'),
    (101, 'L')

select s.rowId
      , s.salesId
      , s.element
      , case when element = 's' 
             then 0 
             else (s.rowId - (select max(d.rowId) 
                               from #SalesWithId d
                              where d.salesId = s.salesId
                                    and d.rowId < s.rowId
                                    and d.element = 's')) 
        end as elementCount
  from #SalesWithId s
order by s.rowId
```